# I have query in which i want result where the recods(pids) does not attached job coded 74 if record has 44, so far I have below query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below are tables people has iformation of people name PID and all `people_jobs` has information of `Job codes` like `71`, `72`, `73`, `74`, `44`, `55`... I want a result where **job code is** `44` but `74` **is not there** (**not in** (`74`)) like this and with current query there is not an issue , just want to add condition **not in** `74`

```
select aa.pid
     , aa.contid
     , bb.fnm
     , bb.mnm
     , bb.lnm
     , bb.sufx
     , aa.title
     , wm_concat(cc.job) as jobs
  from people aa
  join mmd_all_people bb 
    on aa.contid = bb.contid
  join people_jobs cc 
    on aa.pid = cc.pid 
   and aa.seq = cc.seq 
 group by aa.pid
        , aa.contid
        , bb.fnm
        , bb.mnm
        , bb.lnm
        , bb.sufx
        , aa.title    
having (wm_concat(cc.job)) like '%44%'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) Also explain what's wrong with your current query. (Make it easy to assist you, [mcve].)

Comment: I'm using Oracle, below are tables 
people has iformation of people name PID and all
people_jobs has information of Job codes like 71 72 73 74 44 55...(importat one)


I want a result where job code is 44 but 74 is not there not in (74) like this
and with current query there is not an issue , just want add condition not in 74

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead. (And remove the <mysql> tag at the same time.)

Comment: But query is right, what do you want me to change

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider `exists` with a `where` condition to filter them out :

```
select aa.pid,
       aa.contid,
       bb.fnm,
       bb.mnm,
       bb.lnm,
       bb.sufx,
       aa.title,
       wm_concat(cc.job) as jobs
  from people aa
  join mmd_all_people bb
    on aa.contid = bb.contid
  join people_jobs cc
    on aa.pid = cc.pid
   and aa.seq = cc.seq
 where exists ( select 1 
                  from people_jobs 
                 where pid = cc.pid
                   and (( cc.job  = 44 and cc.job != 74 ) or cc.job != 44 )
                    )  
 group by aa.pid, aa.contid, 
          bb.fnm, bb.mnm, bb.lnm, bb.sufx, 
          aa.title
```

where I assumed `cc.jod` is a non-null field and didn't apply any `nvl()` operation it.

As a side note `vm_concat()` is unsupported. Rather, use `listagg()` provided your DBMS has version `11.2` at least.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
having sum(case when cc.job = 44 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

That is, count the number of "44"s and return rows that have at least one.

There is no need to concatenate the values together.  Or to convert numbers to strings for this purpose.

EDIT:

For the comment:

```
having sum(case when cc.job = 44 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when cc.job = 74 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Yes but I want also result where record should not have 74

Comment: @muiz. .  . That is a simple tweak to the condition.

Comment: having sum(case when cc.job = 44 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when cc.job = 74 then 1 else 0 end) = 0

this is still showing data with 74, I dont want those result which is having job 74, but result should be having 44

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ee.pid,
               '44 and no 74' AS Instructions,
               ee.coname,
               enum.totass,--, pf.source as Username ,
               Wm_concat(DISTINCT cc.job) AS jobs
        FROM   entities ee
               join entnums enum
                 ON ee.pid = enum.pid
               join people aa
                 ON ee.pid = aa.pid
               join mmd_all_people bb
                 ON aa.contid = bb.contid
               join people_jobs cc
                 ON aa.pid = cc.pid
                    AND aa.seq = cc.seq
        WHERE  ee.mmd = 'A'
               AND ( ( ee.mmd_cat ) IN ( 5, 10, 15, 20,
                                         25, 28, 30, 38, 66 ) )
               AND ( ( enum.totass ) > 50000 )
        GROUP  BY ee.pid,
                  ee.coname,
                  enum.totass
        HAVING Wm_concat(DISTINCT cc.job) LIKE '%44%'
               AND Wm_concat(DISTINCT cc.job) NOT LIKE '%74%
```